# How do I use the Rectangle object

Tags: java, object, constructor

So I'm trying to create a Rectangle object for this assignment in my java book but everytime I write that exact code, I get an error.

```
package rectangle;

public class Rectangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle box = new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30);
        System.out.println("Before: " + box.getx());
        box.translate(25, 40);
        System.out.println("After: " + box.getx());

    }

}
```

Comment: Your `Rectangle` class doesnt have a constructor that takes 4 integers so you need to add one

Comment: Post your error message so others with same error would be able to find this question and potential solution to their problem. It also helps us help you better.

Comment: First of all you should post an error too in order help us, help you. Second,   there is some code missing from your `Rectangle` Class, you have no `Constructor`, no `getx` method no internal variables ... so thereyou go - fix all the above

Comment: change `box.getx()` to `box.getX();`

Comment: Are you trying to use java.awt.Rectangle ? Then take a look at  @Pshemo 's link,

Comment: If you think that this question is not duplicate feel free to [edit] it and clarify what problem exactly are you facing which is different from one described in duplicate.